# PC restored from Windows Home Server does not boot

Tags: windows-home-server, windows-7-restore

All the PC at my office are connected to a server running Windows Home Server which do backup every night.

We bought a new PC with a Windows7 Home Premium license to replace a dying one running on Windows7 Home Premium and I have used the WHS Restore CD to restore the old PC on the new one.

The restoration ended correctly but the new PC does not boot. The error message is:

> Status: 0xc000000e
>
> Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible

I have searched on Google how to fix that, but none of the solution I have tried worked.
Almost every solution need an Windows7 installation disk, which I do not have. However, before doing the restore, I did a Restore CD on the new PC. But when I start it, it tell me that "This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair".
If I select " Restore you computer using a system image", and then "Cancel" I have acess to the "System Recover Option" menu with "Startup Repair", "System Recovery", etc.

From that menu I have tried "Startup Repair" which complete successfully but does not solve the problem.

I have also tried to use the BootRec tool from the command line( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392 ). The "bootred /RebuildBcd" command find 1 Windows7 installation, I add it to the BootList but I still have the same problem. And if I use the command "bootrec /ScanOs" the result is "Total Identified installations :0".

I do not have the BOOTSECT.EXE application on the recovery disk ( http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html ).

From the command line, I have browsed some folder and found files that were on the old PC which make me believe that the restore has been done.

Finally I have used the WHS RestoreCD 3 times with no success each time.

Is there anything else I could try to fix that problem, or do I have to re-install everything?

Comment: It could be a hard disk driver issue because you're restoring a system image from a different computer (with different hardware).